# Compression on CUPS Print Server

Tags: networking, server, printing

I have a server at home with CUPS install and I am using it as a print server (1 usb photo printer and 1 network color printer). Using DDNS & port fowarding on my SOHO router, I am printing from across the internet to my home network.

I am thinking of implementing compression on the IPP print stream so that I won’t use so much 4G (LTE) data when I am printing over the WAN. I read from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) that Gzip can be used, but I am not sure how to implement compression algorithm and would appreciate anyone who can provide some tips and advise on how to do so. If you have any links to tutorials that would also be great.

Thank you in advance!